# binding jquery widget with underscores or dot

Tags: jquery, binding, namespaces, widget

i have a jquery widget with namespace

```
$.widget( "mynamespace.mywidget" , {...
```

i have an option named foo

```
foo: function(){}
```

i trigger an event with this._trigger

```
this._trigger('foo', event, ...
```

now i can set the foo option bind with

```
var elem = $('#myelem').mywidget();

elem.bind('mywidgetfoo',function(e,v){ alert("fool"); });
```

My Problem ist the binding. I think 'mywidgetfoo' is hard to read. I would prefer something like

```
elem.bind('mywidget.foo',
```

or

```
elem.bind('mywidget_foo'
```

Any chance to achive that?

Comment: `_foo` would simply be `_trigger("_foo", ...`  however the `.` isn't an option because that would be considered a namespace, not an event name.

Comment: Yes, true about "_foo" but i definitely don`t like the name of a event beeing _something considered that you also can set the callback via options and the leading underscore should be for private stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found that i can use the widgets option:

```
widgetEventPrefix: 'mywidget.event.'
```

wich produces events like:

```
mywidget.event.foo
```

Thats what i wanted.